# IDL 7.1.2; How to plot negative correlation in Taylor diagram

Tags: statistics, climate, syntax, idl

I am working on a model's run performance evaluation, three runs of GFDL-CM2.0 and five runs of GFDL-CM2.1 are used for temperature and precipitation for the years 1979-2000. The objective is to validate the runs with respect to observed data sets e.g CMAP for precipitation and NCEP/NCAR for temperature. In this regard I want to plot a Taylor diagram. I am using "cgtaylordiagram", but this code generates only positive correlations on plot and my data have some negative correlations as well with respect to the observed dataset. Further more I need some guidance regarding the RMS corporation in Taylor diagram.
The following code is being used and shows only positive correlations on plot:

> !P.CHARSIZE = [0.5] 
>      labels = ['2.0R1', '2.0R2', '2.0R3', '2.1R1', '2.1R2', '2.1R3', '2.1R4', '2.1R5']
>      stddev = [0.23, 0.15, 0.39, 0.27, 0.28, 0.12, 0.18, 0.08]
>      correlation = [-0.96, -0.86, 1.00, 0.95, 0.33, 1.00, -0.11, 0.47]
>      ref_std = 0.22
>      stddev_max = 0.5
>      OVERPLOT=overplot
>      cgTaylorDiagram, stddev, correlation, REF_STDDEV=ref_std, $
>        STDDEV_MAX=stddev_max, LABELS=labels, OUTPUT='taylor56.png'
>    END

Is there alternative code or method that can plot negative correlation as well in the diagram?
Note: I did not find any solution for e

Comment: Is there a GIS component to this question?  To me it looks like pure stats and a better fit for [stats.se].

Comment: @PolyGeo I agree with that assessment.  However, the question is so specialized and full of jargon and abbreviations that, unless further clarified, it would likely be quickly closed if migrated to [stats.SE].  That it ends suddenly in the middle of a sentence also indicates a need for improvement.